# Range Slider not working on internet explore except working on other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, plugins

My range slider is not working on internet explore 11 except all the other browser is support this plugin 100% and also working fine.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".slider").rangeslider();
});
$.fn.rangeslider = function(options) {
  var obj = this;
  var defautValue = obj.attr("value");
  obj.wrap("<span class='range-slider'></span>");
  obj.after("<span class='slider-container'><span class='bar'><span></span></span><span class='bar-btn'><span>0</span></span></span>");
  obj.attr("oninput", "updateSlider(this)");
  updateSlider(this);
  return obj;
};

function updateSlider(passObj) {
  var obj = $(passObj);
  var value = obj.val();
  var min = obj.attr("min");
  var max = obj.attr("max");
  var range = Math.round(max - min);
  var percentage = Math.round((value - min) * 100 / range);
  var nextObj = obj.next();
  nextObj.find("span.bar-btn").css("left", percentage + "%");
  nextObj.find("span.bar > span").css("width", percentage + "%");
  nextObj.find("span.bar-btn > span").text(percentage);
};
```

```css
.range-slider {
    margin: 30px 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

.range-slider>input {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.range-slider>input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    z-index: 100;
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}

.range-slider>span.slider-container {
    // min-height: 110px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: -8px;
    right: 46px;
    z-index: 3;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.range-slider>span.slider-container>span.bar {
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 17px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.range-slider>span.slider-container>span.bar>span {
    background: #d7302d;
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right bottom, color-stop(0, #d7302d), color-stop(100%, #e82573));
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #d7302d 0, #e82573 100%);
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0%;
}

.range-slider>span.slider-container>span.bar-btn {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font: 600 16px "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    line-height: 38px;
}

.range-slider>span.slider-container>span.bar-btn:after {
    content: "";
    background-color: #cc202e;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #cc202e;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px rgba(204, 32, 46, 0.2)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Please Select</h1>
<input class="slider" value="20" min="0" max="100" name="rangeslider" type="range" />
```

I have been banging my head with this code from last two days. I cannot get any answer for this from many sites. I have searched google and w3schools to get help but I don't think so that they can help me anyways.

So, I came here and posting the question

If anyone can solve this issue that would be really appreciated.

Comment: you never mentioned the version for IE, I am using windows and for me it is working perfectly on IE 10.

Comment: @AliAslam i made the change

Comment: As a side note, there is no  HTML element of type `document`. `$("document")` should be `$(document)`, you are just lucky pseudo ready event can be bound on empty set while parsing page. BTW, what is the issue? Error in console or nothing happen or what?!

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks for your update I made the changes.

Comment: But do you have any error in console or what?

Comment: @A.Wolff No i didn't got any error

Comment: looks like the `oninput` isn't triggered while using `IE`

Comment: just posted an answer for you, see if it works for you

Comment: Can you please mark the answer as correct if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) and [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) events to get a consistent user experience in all browsers:

```
 $(this).on("change input", function() {
   updateSlider(this);
 });
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".slider").rangeslider();
});
$.fn.rangeslider = function(options) {
  var obj = this;
  var defautValue = obj.attr("value");
  obj.wrap("<span class='range-slider'></span>");
  obj.after("<span class='slider-container'><span class='bar'><span></span></span><span class='bar-btn'><span>0</span></span></span>");
  $(this).on("change input", function() {
    updateSlider(this)
  });
  return obj;
};

function updateSlider(passObj) {

  var obj = $(passObj);
  var value = obj.val();
  var min = obj.attr("min");
  var max = obj.attr("max");
  var range = Math.round(max - min);
  var percentage = Math.round((value - min) * 100 / range);
  var nextObj = obj.next();
  nextObj.find("span.bar-btn").css("left", percentage + "%");
  nextObj.find("span.bar > span").css("width", percentage + "%");
  nextObj.find("span.bar-btn > span").text(percentage);
};
```

```css
.range-slider {
  margin: 30px 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.range-slider>input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.range-slider>input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}

.range-slider>span.slider-container {
  // min-height: 110px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -8px;
  right: 46px;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.range-slider>span.slider-container>span.bar {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 17px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.range-slider>span.slider-container>span.bar>span {
  background: #d7302d;
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right bottom, color-stop(0, #d7302d), color-stop(100%, #e82573));
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #d7302d 0, #e82573 100%);
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0%;
}

.range-slider>span.slider-container>span.bar-btn {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font: 600 16px "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  line-height: 38px;
}

.range-slider>span.slider-container>span.bar-btn:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #cc202e;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #cc202e;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px rgba(204, 32, 46, 0.2)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Please Select</h1>
<input class="slider" value="20" min="0" max="100" name="rangeslider" type="range" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace this code with the old one

```
$(function() {
  $(".slider").rangeslider();
});
$.fn.rangeslider = function(options) {
  var obj = this;
  var defautValue = obj.attr("value");
  obj.wrap("<span class='range-slider'></span>");
  obj.after("<span class='slider-container'><span class='bar'><span></span></span><span class='bar-btn'><span>0</span></span></span>");
  $(obj).on("change", function() {
    updateSlider(this)
  });
  return obj;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well looks like you need to use the jquery `onchange` for the slider object to update and trigger the `updateSlider()` function, tho it is a bit choppy in IE 11 but it started to update it, in IE, you can further make improvements, see code below

```js
$(function() {
  $(".slider").rangeslider();
});
$.fn.rangeslider = function(options) {
  var obj = this;
  var defautValue = obj.attr("value");
  obj.wrap("<span class='range-slider'></span>");
  obj.after("<span class='slider-container'><span class='bar'><span></span></span><span class='bar-btn'><span>0</span></span></span>");
  $(obj).on("change", function() {
    updateSlider(this)
  });
  return obj;
};

function updateSlider(passObj) {

  var obj = $(passObj);
  var value = obj.val();
  var min = obj.attr("min");
  var max = obj.attr("max");
  var range = Math.round(max - min);
  var percentage = Math.round((value - min) * 100 / range);
  var nextObj = obj.next();
  nextObj.find("span.bar-btn").css("left", percentage + "%");
  nextObj.find("span.bar > span").css("width", percentage + "%");
  nextObj.find("span.bar-btn > span").text(percentage);
};
```

```css
.range-slider {
  margin: 30px 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.range-slider>input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.range-slider>input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}

.range-slider>span.slider-container {
  // min-height: 110px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -8px;
  right: 46px;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.range-slider>span.slider-container>span.bar {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 17px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.range-slider>span.slider-container>span.bar>span {
  background: #d7302d;
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right bottom, color-stop(0, #d7302d), color-stop(100%, #e82573));
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #d7302d 0, #e82573 100%);
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0%;
}

.range-slider>span.slider-container>span.bar-btn {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font: 600 16px "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  line-height: 38px;
}

.range-slider>span.slider-container>span.bar-btn:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #cc202e;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #cc202e;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px rgba(204, 32, 46, 0.2)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Please Select</h1>
<input class="slider" value="20" min="0" max="100" name="rangeslider" type="range" />
```

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam thanks for the effort but and now its working fine on IE11 but all the other browser is not working as fine as they were working in the past

Comment: add both events change and input , like `$(obj).on("change input",function() ` the demo was for IE 11 specifically